# List of virtualenvs

Tags: macos, osx-lion, python-2.7, virtualenv

Silly question...I created a virtualenv months ago and can't remember what it's called. Where can I find it?

- OSX 10.7
- Python 2.7.1
- Virtualenv 1.6.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I recommend you to use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), after install it you can do:

```
$ lsvirtualenv
```

I also recommend you to use `-b` ("brief" abreviation) option to go faster:

```
$ lsvirtualenv -b
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23634104/4288043) answer helped me get that running.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a *virtualenv* actually creates a new folder with that name. You have to find that folder.

Comment: I used finder to search for "activate" and was able to find it. Thanks!