# virtualenvwrapper commands aren't working

Tags: virtualenvwrapper

```
tow-81-235:Projects pessimisticoptimism$ mkvirtualenv development
-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found
tow-81-235:Projects pessimisticoptimism$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
Password:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Cleaning up...
tow-81-235:Projects pessimisticoptimism$ mkvirtualenv development
-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

Why am I getting this error? I have `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` installed. I'd like to use `mkvirtualenv` and `workon`. I find it odd that `virtualenv` is working, but `virtualenvwrapper` isn't.

Answer (score 185):

1st, ensure you're installing with sudo:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

2nd, append the following lines to your .bashrc file (with `nano ~/.bashrc`):

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

3rd, reload your profile

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Worked for me..! thnx

Comment: After i close my teminal. When i open again the workon command doesn't work.. it occurs 'command not found' is there any way to be permanent active? so i can to do 'source .venvs/app/bin/activate' every time i open my terminal ??

Comment: Hi @ePascoal, the lines in the .bashrc are supposed to make it the changes permanent. Every time you launch a terminal it reads the current user's .bashrc (assuming you are using bash as your shell).  You should be able to add `workon app` under the 3rd line (`source ...) in your .bashrc to make it automatically activate each time.

Comment: **MAC USERS** - Use `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc` like [Will](http://stackoverflow.com/users/464923/will)'s answer suggests.

Comment: To make it permanent, make sure you are adding the two lines (export... and source...) to your ~/.bahrc file, and not only copying and pasting the commands in the terminal!

Comment: seems this issue is very common. Why don't authors of virtualenv fix it for permanent?

Comment: Hi @KishorPawar, virtualenvwrapper is a standard shell script.  The reason for adding it to .bashrc is so that it can create the virtual environment mappings (i.e. `mkvirtualenv`) every time you open the terminal without having to call the script yourself every time.

Comment: That is what my question is, why can't these lines be added to .bashrc during installation only?

Answer (score 37):

**Summary**

I'm on a Mac and my answer is similar to @Ramces answer except it was with bash_profile.  I just want to elaborate a little further for Mac users to be aware that there's a lot of different profiles including:

- .bashrc
- .bash_profile
- .profile

Some files like .profile do not take precedence over .bash_profile (if it exists) and will then be ignored.  If you successfully do the below steps and get a virtual env working, but then close out your terminal and 'workon command not found', then you need to setup for the correct profile.  For a detailed answer, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/479703/profile-and-bashrc-doesnt-work-on-my-mac)

**Install Steps:**

1. `sudo pip install virtualenv`

   Installs virtualenv (allows you to separate your envrionments)
2. `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`

   Installs virtualenvwrapper (allows you to use the 'workon' command)
3. `nano ~/.bash_profile`

   ```
   export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
   source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
   ```
4. `source ~/.bash_profile`

   Reloads the profile.  Going forward you only need step 5 (to create new environments) and step 6 (to run environments)
5. `mkvirtualenv my_env`

   This creates your virtual environment (this example is with 'my_env')
6. `workon my_env`

   This lets you work on a specific environment (this example is with 'my_env')

Comment: Worked like a charm on my computer. Thanks :)

Comment: I want to run workon my_env with sudo. sudo workon my_env says workon: command not found. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi, i have a problem that my virtualenvwrpper.sh doesnt exist in /usr/local/bin/ it exists in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/virtualenvwrapper.$

Answer (score 10):

After installing the `virtualenvwrapper` package using `pip`, you also have to do some initialisation/set your preferences. See the [introduction in the virtualenvwrapper docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#introduction).

Most relevant for finding the commands should be *sourcing the virtualenvwrapper script* into your shell. In the docs it is mentioned as

```
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

You still have to adjust the path to your setup. My guess for your Mac would be:

```
$ source /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: If you are already in the virtual environment, the virtualenvwrapper.sh is in the bin folder of that virtual environment itself like below { source ~/mypythonenv/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh     }

Answer (score 9):

Simple process

1. sudo apt-get install python-pip(if pip is not installed)
2. sudo pip install virtualenv
3. Create a dir to store your virtualenvs

   mkdir ~/.virtualenvs
4. sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
5. Run following command

   export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
6. Add virtualenvwrapper.sh to .bashrc
   Add this line to the end of ~/.bashrc so that the virtualenvwrapper      commands are loaded.

   . /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
7. you will find .bashrc.sh file in home directory by doing ctrl+h. if not then use find command to find .bashrc.sh "file ls -la ~/ | more"
8. Hit this command

   source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
9. Hit this command

   source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have multiple Python installations on your machine and virtualenvwrapper is not pointing to the right Python.

Find out which Python virtualenvwrapper is using. You get a hint where to look with `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` (In this case `/usr/local/bin`):

```
> /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

If you don't get any return here make sure you use the correct pip when installing. The `pip` command might link to a different Python then you expect. Check your `usr/local/bin` directory for pip links (`pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.5`). It is easy to get system `pip`, `pip2` and `pip2.7` mixed up.

After you have found the Python location, add/update all paths in your `.profile`:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/venv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Finally reload your profile: `source ~/.profile`

Comment: Why you are using $HOME/Envs and not $HOME/venv? Also I get the error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable Any clue what is going on, please?

Comment: `Envs` is an arbitrary choice. I like `venv` better as it is all lowercase :) Re `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable` you might have reached your system’s maximum number of processes (either system-wide or per user or you ran out of memory).

Answer (score 2):

I am on Mac OS X 10.9.2 and for me `virtualenvwrapper.sh` file was present in

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

So I simply copied this into `~/.profile` file:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And now my `~/.profile` file looks something like this:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-02-23_at_17:28:39: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And now I am able to use `virtualenvwrapper` commands without any issue whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

Users of the Anaconda (from Continuum) distribution of Python should note that

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

will be anaconda-aware. So if you

```
which python
```

that should give you an idea of where to point your virtualenv in your .bashrc and/or .profile configuration files.

Comment: pip can link to another python. `which pip` and `pip -V` will give you a better idea to which python pip is linked to and therefore virtualenvwrapper.