# Having trouble using virtualenvwrapper commands

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am new to virtual environments and am trying to get lsvirtualenv to run. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232421/virtualenvwrapper-commands-arent-working) stack overflow post thus far, but I am currently getting following error whenever I try to source the bash_profile:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I am guessing I have just installed my virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper files in the wrong directory, but I can't figure out how to get pip to install them correctly.

Comment: find the file called virtualenvwrapper.sh, and move it to that folder

Comment: `pip show --files virtualenvwrapper`