# virtualenvwrapper commands unavailable

Tags: python, bash, virtualenvwrapper

The same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232421/virtualenvwrapper-commands-arent-working); still something else is missing.

Install:

```
$ sudo pacman -S python-virtualenvwrapper
...
$ which virtualenvwrapper.sh
/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

~/.profile:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Sourcing it:

```
$ source .profile 
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/premkproject
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/postmkproject
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/initialize
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/premkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/postmkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/prermvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/postrmvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/alexey/.virtualenvs/get_env_details
[alexey@stovepipebox ~]$ workon
[alexey@stovepipebox ~]$
```

Everything looks fine; unfortunately, any other session won't see the wrapper commands. After relogin they are still invisible. What am I doing wrong?

UPD:

`pacman` modified my `.bashrc`; I just had to uncomment `source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` statement in `.bashrc`, then

```
$ source .bashrc
```

It's Arch specific.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Is it configured to source `.profile` when you log in?

Comment: `bash`. How do I have to check the sourcing on login? I can only tell that everything else in `.profile` logs in well.

Comment: A simple diagnostic is to `echo` something from `.profile` and see if it appears in you teminal when you log in. Bash will prefer `.bash_profile` if that exists; a comron arrangement is to source `.profile` from `.bash_profile`; but remember that `.profile` s used by other shells too (so you should use the standard syntax `.` (dot) instead of the Bash-only alias `source` within that file).

Comment: `export variable=value` is also not POSIX; you want `variable=value; export variable`

Comment: Semicolon, however proper, can't be the root of all evil, I hope. Yes, there is something wrong with echoing: `EDITOR` does not look as expected, for instance. Probably, I need a proper policy on using `.bashrc` and `.profile`. I remember that I had to use `.profile` once because `.bashrc` won't do. Clearly I lack understanding.

Comment: Try moving this code to `.bash_profile` for a start. As indicated above, if you have other code in `.profile` which should be shared between shells, also make sure to `source .profile` from `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I will have to create `.bash_profile` first. Would it interfere with `.bashrc`?

Comment: As discussed in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) you *probably* want to `source .bashrc` from `.bash_profile` for consistency.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to research it. Meanwhile, I should have paid more attention to detail: the package manager modified `.bashrc`; I just had to uncomment the `source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` statement in `.bashrc`.