# Python How to create virtual environment in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python and I'm following a tutorial which requires creating a virtual environment while creating a Python project,
But I am unable to create one for some reasons,
**I am using the command -**

```
mkvirtualenv djangoenv
```

**But it displays -**

```
bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

Most recommended using PyCharm but, as I have work on JS as well, I wish to continue using VS Code

**Following are the steps that I tried -**

[image]

**I checked, the `virtualenvwrapper` is installed on my machine -**
[image]

**My `~/.bash_profile` file, looks like this -**

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: Don't post pictures of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at [this answer for Mac users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23634104/9477714). Be sure that the `$PATH` is set before sourcing `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in your `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

It seems mkvirtualenv isn't installed on your system. 
First of all make sure you have python and pip installed then follow this instruction. 
https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-win/

Comment: Hi, I doubled checked, I had installed it using the following command - `pip install virtualenvwrapper`